# Unable to get response using retrofit in android

Tags: android, retrofit

https://api.tj.com/orderNumber/order

Request Paremeter:

```
Header 
Authorization: Beer naskjnkjnsadsad
Content-Type:application/json

Body json:

{
  "orderRequestId" : "890329jnfndlsd",
  "stateOfOldOrder" : "NotComplted"
}
```

Response:

```
raw response : HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Fri, 31 Aug 2018 09:39:47 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
ID: jhdsahjksa219212
Connection: keep-alive
```

response should come in header
This is my excepted output which is working fine in Postman

but in using retrofit i am trying this code

```
@POST("orderNumber/order") 
Observable<ResponseBody> requestOrderCard(@Body OrderRequest request);
```

and calling like this :

```
orderService.requestOrderCard(request)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map(voidResponse -> {
                    Log.d("RESPONSEsss","vodiresponse");
                    return voidResponse;
                })

                .subscribe(voidResponse -> {
                            Log.d("RESPONSEsss","vodiresponse");
                        },
                        error -> {
                            Log.d("ERRRROOOR","Error");
                        });
```

But each time i am getting error please suggest me how to get response when no Content only Header in Post method in retrofit  in android .

Comment: please update proper API

Answer (score 0):

use single instead of observable

```
@POST("orderNumber/order")
Single<Response<OBJECT>>  requestOrderCard(@Body OrderRequest)
```

retrieve retrive like this

```
listSingle.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<OBJECT>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Response<OBJECT> objectdto) {
                            if (objectdto.code() == 200 && objectdto.body() != null) {
                                getMvpView().sucess(objectdto.body());
                            } else if (objectdto.errorBody() != null) {
                                getMvpView().setErrorMessage(objectdto.errorBody());
                            } 
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            getMvpView().setErrorMessage("Something went Wrong");
                        }
                    });
```

And your object will be

```
OBJECT.java

private class OBJECT{
{
  private String orderRequestId;
  private String stateOfOldOrder;

}
```

Comment: we dont have any Response in Object its empty Content